# Python bcrypt: Password from different python & bcrypt library versions isn't recognized

Tags: python, flask, passwords, bcrypt

I'm using the same algorithm to generate passwords between 2 different environments:
`Env A: Python 3.8 | bcrypt==3.2.0`
`Env B: Python 3.7 | bcrypt==0.3.2`

The hashed & salted password I've saved to the database works correctly at Env A, but when I use it at the Env B it doesn't.

Also, hashed passwords saved from Env B, are correctly recognized by Env A.

Did `bcrypt` changed the way it creates hashes?

**EDIT #1**

Thank you for the input!
Raw dummy password string: `A12345!a`

- Env A hash: `$2b$13$IANN8RRLYB6EPUM8rwYkvuwUfL9IcKKNPBgScrBhUK9DJEpb41wzy`
- Env B hash: `$2a$13$GG4RNYg8iDDy60JQKHsyhuxWGqeBksfzsbtcB9uaiS8v8RsTKc4w2`

Also I've created a local venv for 3.7, with the library versions of Env B, I was able to recreate the error.

1. Then I've updated bcrypt (latest), got the error `AttributeError: module 'bcrypt._bcrypt' has no attribute 'hashpass'`
2. Replaced `bcrypt` with `py-bcrypt` (latest), the app run, but I got the past behavior (not recognizing the passwords generated from Env A).
3. The snippet of the code is very simple:

```
from bcrypt import gensalt, hashpw
hash_p = hashpw(time_now.encode("utf-8"), gensalt(13))
```

**EDIT #2**

After searching the libraries of Env B locally, I've found that `python-bcrypt` was used from (local)Env B & `bcrypt` from Env A.

I've replaced `python-bcrypt`(0.3.2) with `bcrypt`(latest) at (local)Env B and now both password hashes are decrypted correctly.

So the question now is, before I proceed with these changes:
`pip uninstall python-bcrypt && pip install bcrypt`
at the actual Env B environment, should I take (test) anything else into consideration?

Comment: The problem could be any of a thousand different things.  You need to give us a complete program that demonstrates the issue.